# linux sort unexpected output

Tags: shell

I use sort file

```
ABC
AB-C
ABCDEFG-HI
```

I get

```
ABC
AB-C
ABCDEFG-HI
```

why does sort orders the string this way?  how do I make it sort '-' alphabetically?

Comment: Please post the exact `sort` call you're using, you're likely doing it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution provided by @cnicutar is correct, but the reason needs explanation which is why I'm giving a new answer.

After the discussion with @cnicutar where in the end I suspected a bug in coreutils' `sort` I found that [this sorting behavior is expected](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#Sort-does-not-sort-in-normal-order_0021):

> At that point sort appears broken because case is folded and punctuation is ignored because ‘en_US.UTF-8’ specifies this behavior.

So to `sort`, your input seems to be mapped as follows:

```
ABC -> ABC
AB-C -> ABC
ABCDEFG-HI -> ABCDEFGHI
```

If you want pure ASCII sorting, you need to call `LC_ALL=C sort` (temporarily set the locale to `C` when calling `sort` which means "standard" behavior without localization; you can also use `POSIX` instead of `C`).

On other Unixes this behavior seems to be different (tested on Mac OS X which userland tools are derived from FreeBSD), but `LC_ALL=C sort` should yield the same behavior across all POSIX systems.

Answer (score 3):

I remember this :)) try

```
[cnicutar@aiur ~]$ LANG=POSIX sort
ABC
AB-C
ABCDEFG-HI
AB-C
ABC
ABCDEFG-HI
```

Alternatively `LANG=C` should work.

Comment: In no language setting should the `AB-C` appear in the middle (not even with EBCDIC), so I bet that this isn't the problem but instead the way user678070 is calling `sort`.

Comment: @DarkDust I just tried it with different `LANG`s. For `en_US.utf8` it does what the op says (I had this problem before). Do a `locale -a` and pick some.

Comment: @cnicutar: I just tried it myself and I still get the correct sorting. And given that only ASCII characters are used, I very much doubt `en_US.utf8` would result in this strange sorting as UTF-8 has ASCII as a subset. Do you get the "unsorted" output when using `LANG=foobar` ? If so, then your `sort` doesn't sort when it can't find the locale.

Comment: @DarkDust What coreutils version are you using ? What does `echo $LANG` say ? What does `locale -a` say ? If you try to use a locale that's unavailable it is ignored. Btw, "I very much doubt" regarding **to what I just said I tested** sounds a bit offensive, don't you think ?

Comment: @DarkDust Even if I reorder the words, with LANG=en_US.utf8 I still get the order of the OP. And `locale -a` shows I have it available.

Comment: @cnicutar: My comment wasn't meant to be offensive and was about *"UTF-8 should not result in different sorting than POSIX in this case"*. Also, given that 1) the output is exactly as the input, 2) ASCII and UTF-8 should both result in different sorting I was merely expecting that no sorting takes place due to incorrect `LANG`. Anyway, I was testing on Mac OS X where it behaves as expected, testing on a Linux does indeed yield the strange/wrong output. This does look like a coreutils bug to me.

Comment: @DarkDust Okay, no problem. Perhaps it's a bug :-/

Comment: @cnicutar: I found out what's happening, see my answer.