# UNIX Full Outer Join creates duplicate entries items despite correct order? Could it be the unpaired items creating disorder?

Tags: unix, join, left-join, bioinformatics, outer-join

I have two files that I want to join based on their first column.

They are sorted, and not all of the values in the first column in FILE1 are in FILE2, and viceversa.

FILE1.TXT looks something like this, except it is around 15k lines:

```
snRNA:7SK   1037
snRNA:U11   144
snRNA:U1:21D    348.293
snRNA:U12:73B   16
snRNA:U1:82Eb   2.14286
snRNA:U1:95Ca   348.293
snRNA:U1:95Cb   351.96
snRNA:U1:95Cc   35.5095
snRNA:U2:14B    447.35
snRNA:U2:34ABa  459.75
snRNA:U2:34ABb  513.25
snRNA:U2:34ABc  509
snRNA:U2:38ABa  443.65
snRNA:U4:38AB   155
snRNA:U4:39B    611.833
snRNA:U4atac:82E    152.5
snRNA:U5:14B    1
snRNA:U5:23D    2.5
snRNA:U5:34A    11
snRNA:U5:38ABb  2.5
snRNA:U5:63BC   44
snRNA:U6:96Aa   18
snRNA:U6:96Ab   9.5
snRNA:U6:96Ac   8.5
snRNA:U7    4
snRNA:U8    8
```

FILE2.TXT looks like this, it is also ~15K lines:

```
snRNA:7SK   1259
snRNA:U11   33
snRNA:U1:21D    1480.57
snRNA:U12:73B   4
snRNA:U1:82Eb   10.2
snRNA:U1:95Ca   1480.57
snRNA:U1:95Cb   1484.03
snRNA:U1:95Cc   114.633
snRNA:U2:14B    4678.89
snRNA:U2:34ABa  4789.93
snRNA:U2:34ABb  5292.22
snRNA:U2:34ABc  5273.23
snRNA:U2:38ABa  4557.88
snRNA:U2:38ABb  3.75
snRNA:U4:38AB   405
snRNA:U4:39B    1503.5
snRNA:U4atac:82E    548
snRNA:U5:14B    25
snRNA:U5:23D    19
snRNA:U5:34A    32
snRNA:U5:38ABb  4
snRNA:U5:63BC   742
snRNA:U6:96Aa   39.5
snRNA:U6:96Ab   1
snRNA:U6:96Ac   1
snRNA:U7    11
```

As you can see, an element from FILE2 (snRNA:U5:38ABb) is missing IN FILE1, and an element from FILE1 is missing in FILE2. This is the case all through out the files, in both directions and multiple times.

I am writing the command as follows:

```
join -a1 -a2 -e "0" -1 1 -2 1 -o '0,1.2,2.2' -t '        ' 
FILE1.TXT FILE2.TXT
>JOIN_FILE.TXT
```

If I try the command with ONLY the 20 or so lines that I pasted from each file, it works as it should.

But when I run it on the entire files, The output is terrible, and I don't understand why. Both files were sorted using `sort -k1,1`, so even though some lines in 1 are not in 2, and viceversa, they are both in the same order.

What I get is duplicate entries for an item, such as: (again, I'm only showing a fraction of the output file...)

```
snRNA:7SK   0   1037
snRNA:U11   0   144
snRNA:U1:21D    0   348.293
snRNA:U12:73B   0   16
snRNA:U1:82Eb   0   2.14286
snRNA:U1:95Ca   0   348.293
snRNA:U1:95Cb   0   351.96
snRNA:U1:95Cc   0   35.5095
snRNA:U2:14B    0   447.35
snRNA:U2:34ABa  0   459.75
snRNA:U2:34ABb  0   513.25
snRNA:U2:34ABc  0   509
snRNA:U2:38ABa  0   443.65
snRNA:U4:38AB   0   155
snRNA:U4:39B    0   611.833
snRNA:U4atac:82E    0   152.5
snRNA:U5:14B    0   1
snRNA:U5:23D    0   2.5
snRNA:U5:34A    0   11
snRNA:U5:38ABb  0   2.5
snRNA:U5:63BC   0   44
snRNA:U6:96Aa   0   18
snRNA:U6:96Ab   0   9.5
snRNA:U6:96Ac   0   8.5
snRNA:U7    0   4
snRNA:7SK   1259    0
snRNA:U11   33  0
snRNA:U1:21D    1480.57 0
snRNA:U12:73B   4   0
snRNA:U1:82Eb   10.2    0
snRNA:U1:95Ca   1480.57 0
snRNA:U1:95Cb   1484.03 0
snRNA:U1:95Cc   114.633 0
snRNA:U2:14B    4678.89 0
snRNA:U2:34ABa  4789.93 0
snRNA:U2:34ABb  5292.22 0
snRNA:U2:34ABc  5273.23 0
snRNA:U2:38ABa  4557.88 0
snRNA:U2:38ABb  3.75    0
snRNA:U4:38AB   405 0
snRNA:U4:39B    1503.5  0
snRNA:U4atac:82E    548 0
snRNA:U5:14B    25  0
snRNA:U5:23D    19  0
snRNA:U5:34A    32  0
snRNA:U5:38ABb  4   0
snRNA:U5:63BC   742 0
snRNA:U6:96Aa   39.5    0
snRNA:U6:96Ab   1   0
snRNA:U6:96Ac   1   0
snRNA:U7    11  0
```

Where esentially everything has been duplicated, with one line for the value in FILE1 and another line for the value in FILE2. Could this be because of the accumulated differences between the files (i.e., all the non-paired entries before these specific ones?)
This scrambling of the output runs all throughout the file.

What am I doing wrong? Am I not specifying that entries in both files don't always match?

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks a lot!
Carmen

**Edit:**

Here are the first 15 lines of each file, in order to show that the order is the same in both, but things start to get different because items in FILE1 start to appear that are not in FILE2, and viceversa. I wonder if this is what causes the mix-up.

```
==> FILE1 <==
128up   139
140up   170
14-3-3epsilon   4488
14-3-3zeta  24900
18w 885
26-29-p 517
2mit    3085.34
312 64
4EHP    9012.57
5.8SrRNA:CR40454    16.5
5-HT1A  1867
5-HT1B  366
5-HT2   2611.27
5-HT7   1641.67
5PtaseI 462

==> FILE2 <==
128up   80
140up   19
14-3-3epsilon   1718
14-3-3zeta  5554
18w 213
26-29-p 200
2mit    680.786
312 33
4EHP    1838.44
5-HT1A  303
5-HT1B  42
5-HT2   553.65
5-HT7   348.5
5PtaseI 105
5S_DM   46054.4
```

Comment: set `LC_ALL=C` before sorting and joining.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531674

Comment: Thanks, @Pierre! This solved the problem, there are no duplicate entries now. Your link helped a lot, I actually did import these tables into my Mac instead of joining them in the CentOS from work. Probably wouldn't have bumped into this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you have "spaces" instead of "tabs" in one of your files.

Your join command seems to give duplicated entries when there is a space in one of the line:

```sh
#>  bash fjoin.sh 
:: join ::
join: s.file1s.txt:2: is not sorted: 128up  139

:: diff ::
1c1,3
< 128up 139 80
---
> 128up 0   80
> 128up 139 0   0
> 128up 139 0

#>  grep " " file*txt
file1s.txt:128up 139

#>  grep 128up file1s.txt
128up 139
128up   139
```

---

**fjoin.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

f1="file1.txt"
f1s="file1s.txt"
f2="file2.txt"

# sort files & remove duplicate
sort -k 1b,1 ${f1} | uniq > s.${f1}
sort -k 1b,1 ${f1s} | uniq > s.${f1s}
sort -k 1b,1 ${f2} | uniq > s.${f2}

echo ":: join ::"
join -a1 -a2 -e "0" -1 1 -2 1 -o '0,1.2,2.2' -t '   ' s.${f1} s.${f2} > joined-1_f1_f2.txt
join -a1 -a2 -e "0" -1 1 -2 1 -o '0,1.2,2.2' -t '   ' s.${f1s} s.${f2} > joined-2_f1_f2.txt

echo " "
echo ":: diff ::"
diff joined-1_f1_f2.txt joined-2_f1_f2.txt
```

---

**update**

Setting `LC_ALL=C` as Pierre suggested could help.

There are less differences after adding `export LC_ALL=C` to fjoin.sh :

```
#> bash fjoin.sh
:: join ::

:: diff ::
1a2
> 128up 139 0   0
```

Comment: Thanks, David! LC_ALL=C did in fact solve the problem. I looked for spaces in both of the files with cat -vet, but both of them show only tabs and newlines in all lines... I wonder where the spaces could have come from and how to see that they are there?